# OrientDB create constraints on edges in java code

Tags: java, orientdb

I have a few nodes in orientDB and i want to have constraints on the edges between them. For example i have a node type Master and a type Slave and i want to have edges only between master and slave and not between slaves.

I want to do this using a constraint on the relationshiop between master and slave. Is this possible using constraints?

Edit: I tried to do it like this, but it doesnt work, i can still add a slave pointing to a master. How do i access the schema when using a graph DB?

```
OrientGraph graph = new OrientGraph("remote:localhost/test");
    if (graph.getEdgeType("Ref") == null) {
        graph.createEdgeType("Ref");
    }
    if (graph.getVertexType("Element") == null) {
        graph.createVertexType("Element");
    }
    if (graph.getVertexType("SubElement") == null) {
        OrientVertexType subElementVertex = graph
                .createVertexType("SubElement");
        OrientVertexType elementVertex = graph.getVertexType("Element");
        subElementVertex
                .createProperty("parent", OType.LINK, elementVertex)
                .isMandatory();
    }
```

I'm using this to create my vertices and edges:

```
Vertex page3 = graph.addVertex("class:Element");
Vertex doc1 = graph.addVertex("class:SubElement");
page3.setProperty("type", "page");
doc1.setProperty("type", "document");

Edge edge6 = graph.addEdge("class:Ref", page3, doc1, "Ref");
edge6.setProperty("properties", mapEdge);
edge6.setProperty("type", "document");

Edge edge7 = graph.addEdge("class:Ref", doc1, page3, "Ref");
```

And that last one should not work, if the constraint is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the [schema](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Schema.html):

```
Master master = database.getMetadata().getSchema().createClass("Master");

Slave slave = database.getMetadata().getSchema().createClass("Slave");
slave.createProperty("parent", OType.LINK, master);
```

With graphs:

```
OrientEdgeType edge = graph.createEdgeType("MyEdge");
Edge e = subElementVertex.addEdge("Ref", elementVertex );
```

Comment: I can't seem to do this orientdb> create edge Owns from (select from Person) to (select from Car) in java. Do i have to create the properties like that using OCommandSQL?

Comment: The example you posted is already the editing of the schema. To add a node you have to use graph.addVertex(null) not graph.createEdgeType

Comment: I see, you have to change the schema, instead of createProperty use createEdgeType (see my edit)